# Visual Studio Unit Test hangs up when started

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, freeze

I've created the simple "HelloWorld" console application in c#. Then Right Click-> Create module tests... Then Start this test. Column "Result" is showing "Waiting" forever and keeps in the same state when I press Stop test. Also it doesn't hit a  breakpoint at test's first stroke. Why this problem could happen? I've reinstalled .net and visual studio already, but useless;

Comment: Need to see some code in order to answer this.  Post your code including the test code.

Comment: You could try pressing `Ctrl + R + T` simultaneously with the cursor inside the test you want to run with a break point, this will run the test as debug mode. See if that helps.